# Deleting a row based on a certain cell being marked "done"

Tags: google-apps-script

we have a small preschool and I am trying to organize our long TO DO lists. I used to have the correct formula/script but I can't find it anymore... I am looking to have any row deleted based on if Column D is marked "done".

I have a couple of scripts added in and could get some parts working but not exactly as I am hoping. I am not expert so feeling at the end of my capabilities.

I am also hoping to have a menu option on the sheet to be able to manually choose to delete rows as needed. I would then also set up a trigger to run the function probably end the end of each day.

Here is a copy of the sheet: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ksPa78gTtst68D2trnlM1lup7SpmnDJxvmVHg_RtKxQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line:

```
if (row[2] == 0 || row[2] == '') {
```

to

```
if (row[3] == 'Done' || row[3] == 'done') {
```

will work. The `[2]` and `[3]` are column indexes where `[2] == C` and `[3] == D` using the `||` OR operator will delete the row if the value in column D is `Done` or `done`.